# CouchApp and authentication

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I have a two questions about authentication involving CouchDB. The questions are about a CouchApp with private data + a login app.

1. First of all I want to be sure I got this right. If you make a database completely private ( no reading, no writing, no updating, ...) you need an extra public database + app to do the actually logging in right?
2. Does CouchDB have something that if you get a 401 it redirects to something else?

Comment: Have you read discussion at [COUCHDB-1175](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1175)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the discussion at issue 1175 I can answer my own questions.

1. Yes
2. No. In 1175 there is talk about either using a redirect to a login page or use the 401 page to login. But if I understood correctly it's not easy to determent if the source that does the request wants html or json.